# An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Jenkins job is failing to upload results to sonarqube , with below sonar plugin error. Job uses Jenkins sonar plugin.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal
org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar
(default-cli) on project automation-parent: Execution default-cli of
goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar
failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing
org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
org.sonar.api.resources.Project.getFileSystem()Lorg/sonar/api/resources/ProjectFileSystem;
```

Has anyone seen this issue before. I could not find a solution on stack overflow. This is currently blocking our customer builds. 
This error came up after upgrading sonarqube to version 5.6.3. 
sonar-mavem-plugin version is the latest which is 3.2
Jenkins sonarqube plugin version is upgraded to 2.5

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have SonarQube plugins that use method `org.sonar.api.resources.Project.getFileSystem`, however it has been deprecated since 3.5 and removed in 5.3. So please check that you didn't forget to update plugins. And I guess that bigger excerpt of log (lines above error) might help to identify incompatible plugin.